# With notebook's default context set to "Unique to each cell group", how do I make "Evaluate in Place" work in a text cell?

Tags: evaluation, notebooks

With the notebook's default context set to "Unique to each cell group", I have:

```
x=1

The value of x = x
```

where the second line is a text cell with an inline cell (created with Ctrl-9). When I select x in the inline cell and choose `Evaluation->Evaluate in Place`, the value does not update. When the notebook's default context is global, this works as expected. If I ask for the value of `x` in a subsequent cell (in the same cell group as the assignment and the text cell), the value is `1` as expected.

How do I make `Evaluation->Evaluate in Place` work when the notebook's default context is set to "Unique to Each Cell Group"?

Comment: Maybe "the notebook's default context is set to 'Unique to Each Cell Group' isn't such a good idea after all.

Comment: **Evaluate in Place** is still working. It's just you shrunk down the scope of evaluation so much that the evaluator can't see you assignment to `x`. Isn't this a case of wanting to eat your cake but still have it, too?

Comment: The inline cell is in a different cell group. Try `Context[x]` in the inline cell and evaluate it; do the same in a cell in the cell group (with `CellContext` set).

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I guess I understand that the inline cell is in a different cell group, but I'm confused as to why -- and as to whether there is some way to work around the issue. I've got the notebook default context set to "Unique to Each Cell Group" because it's a collection of solutions to problems, and many of the problems use the same symbols (`f`, `x`, etc.). I've set it up so that each problem is its own cell group. Is there some better way to handle such a notebook?

Comment: Actually, if you just select any part of a text cell with the option `CellContext -> CellGroup` and evaluate it in place, the evaluation is done in a unique ``Cell$$nnn` `` context.  Not very useful, that.